# Migrating SMSes from Windows Mobile to Android phone

Tags: sms, data-transfer, windows-mobile

I want to migrate all my SMSs from WinMo to Android.

I currently use PIM Backup to make a backup in case WinMo gets hard resetted, and it works fine. I have complete history of received and sent messages. I tried `SMS Exporter` but it looked like the XML file doesn't contain sent SMS (bad!!)

I tried `Sprite Backup`: it generates a good EXE file with possibly all the messages it in, but I couldn't restore it by copying the generated files into Android SD card and opening Sprite Backup for Android, since it listed no backup file available in SD.

I also read about `Sprite Migrate` from a 2010 blog post, but I see no more traces of it.

What can I do to migrate SMSs? Contacts are no problem: I'll use `LocalSync` for Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this article was made for you: [Import/Export/Move SMS Messages from Windows Mobile to Android](http://android.riteshsahu.com/tips/importexportmove-sms-messages-from-windows-mobile-to-android). It mentions several tools to export your SMS from WinMo to an XML file, which then can be imported on your Android device without involving 3rd party tools. It also links to more useful articles on this topic.

**EDIT:**

As the OP commented, he was successfully using the [Piemaster.NET guide](http://piemaster.net/tools/winmo-android-sms-converter/) mentioned on the page I originally linked. As suggested, I add it here in case the originally linked page is unreachable some day.

Comment: Tried on my tablet (ok, a tablet is not supposed to support SMSes), it seemed to work and import all 493 messages. I'll try to install Android on my phone and make final test :) Upvote for now

Comment: I followed this guide: http://piemaster.net/tools/winmo-android-sms-converter/

Comment: Yepp, that guide was mentioned there. Looks like you are successful -- glad to read!

Comment: May I suggest that you add the actual guide to your answer. In the future if the linked site goes down, your answer will still prove useful.

Comment: @Zuul Good point -- though the OP mentioned the complete link in his comment, I added it to my answer to make it easier to find. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: My suggesting is related to a popular conception that concerns the answer contents: Today the link is useful, a *year* from now you may get downvotes because the site doesn't exist and your answer without the link doesn't solve the problem of the future reader.