# Import SMSes from Nokia 6300

Tags: sms, data-transfer, import

I want to transfer all SMSes from my old phone Nokia 6300 to Philips W626. I have tried several tools but all of them failed. Does anybody know tested way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to import SMSes using [SMS Importer Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.acomba.smsimporterlite&hl=en). This [post](http://www.kerstner.at/en/2012/08/transfer-sms-messages-from-nokia-to-android-devices/) was very helpful to make it work. It was required to configure SMS Importer this way:

- Source type: Custom

in Advanced preferences:

- Seperator: ,
- Sender position: 3
- Date position: 6
- Body position: 8

Otherwise it always failed with "unexpected error" message.

Answer (score 3):

An accepted solution is described with the question [How to move contacts and other data from Symbian to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12836/how-to-move-contacts-and-other-data-from-symbian-to-android) -- which might be of special interest to you, as it covers the transfer of other data as well. The [SMS Migrator](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.baole.app.mainimporter) tool described there does, according to its description...

> 4 steps to migrate / import / transfer / move SMS from Iphone, 
>   Window Mobile, Symbian (Nokia), BlackBerry, Sony Errison, 
>   Samsung, Siemens, and so on to your Android.

A step-by-step guide can be found on the [product's website](http://a.baole.org/home/sms-migrator).

Comment: Probably SMS Migrator will do the job. But it is not free and according to reviews it failed for some people. I don't want to pay for something that will probably fail.

Comment: I understand. As that tool either requires you to first export SMS on your own, you might want to take a look at [Migrating SMSes from Windows Mobile to Android phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/migrating-smses-from-windows-mobile-to-android-phone/26891#26891) -- not the tool itself, but the procedure might help. If you can figure out the XML format used, and convert your exported SMS into it, you will be fine.